# Changing values instantiated objects

Tags: java, swing, object, jpanel

I'm trying to get my head around changing a Boolean in my glasspane:

```
public class Frame extends JFrame{
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Frame f = new Frame();
    MyGlassPane mgp = new MyGlassPane();
    f.setGlassPane(mgp);
    mgp.setVisible(true);
    mgp.setOpaque(false);
            Store s = new Store();
            f.add(s);
            f.pack();
}

public class MyGlassPane extends JPanel{
Boolean show;

    @Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    if(show){
    g.fillRect(50, 50, 50, 50);
    }
}

public class Store extends JPanel{

public Store(){
    setLayout(null);
    But jb1 = new But();
        add(jb1);

    setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

}

}

public class But extends JButton implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
public But(){
        addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);

}
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
//Here I should be able to "show = true", but can't figure out how? 
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Tried creating a public void setShow(Boolean x){ show = x}; in the MyGlassPane class, but couldn't make it work. How can I change the value of the instanciated JPanel's boolean value, so that it draws my rectangle (this should happen when i click a button added to the "otherClass").

Comment: As a side note: you could easily get along using primitive `boolean` type instead of a wrapper class `Boolean`, i.e. `boolean show;`

Comment: You need a reference to the `MyGlassPane` instance.

Comment: Exactly, but how do I pass it from my Frame class, to "otherClass" class ? Or other classes in general ?

Comment: btw when replying to someone (unless the comment is for the author of the answer or the question) use `@username`, so that user would be notified (and to make clear who are you addressing your message to).  Read here: [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Comment: what happens if you initialize the boolean value to true?  is the rectangle displayed correctly?

Comment: @Stephen Carlson: Yes, I just need a general way to change the value in another JPanel.

Comment: @JesperTuborgMadsen, I understand that, just making sure that MyGlassPane was correctly created and bound to the JFrame, and that your paintComponent() code worked.  Just trying to rule out other problems.

Comment: @JesperTuborgMadsen, could you add a method to OtherClass that will allow you to pass the MyGlassPane reference to it?  OtherClass would probably just store this value as an attribute, so that it would be accessible from actionPerformed().

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store a reference on the MyGlassPane objet (it can be static if it's a singleton) :

```
 public class But extends JButton implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {
    private MyGlassPane mgp;
    public But(MyGlassPane mgp){
        this.mgp = mgp;
    }
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        mgp.show = true;
    }
 } 


 public Store(MyGlassPane mgp){
   //..
   But jb1 = new But(mgp);
   //..
 }
```

and finally in your main :

```
 public static void main(St ring[] args) {
     Frame f = new Frame(); 
     MyGlassPane mgp = new MyGlassPane();
     //..
     Store s = new Store(mgp);
     //..
 }
```

Of course, not a very graceful solution, but it should work...